# Ist there a way to determine, if a Product is Fullfilled by Amazon (FBA) or not, without requesting the Fee Estimation

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

i have been working with the function "getMyFeesEstimateForSKU" for the last few days. my goal is to determine the fees for some products, but i keep running into the problem that these items are not "fulfilled by amazon". in my case, i get a client error and am supposed to check my input.

My example article:
https://www.amazon.de/-/dp/B08GLYFTFQ/

my payload is currently as follows:

```
[
    {
        "FeesEstimateRequest": {
            "MarketplaceId": "A1PA6795UKMFR9",
            "IsAmazonFulfilled": true,
            "PriceToEstimateFees": {
                "ListingPrice": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                    "Amount": 36.79
                },
                "Shipping": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                    "Amount": 0
                }
            },
            "Identifier": "unique"
        },
        "IdType": "ASIN",
        "IdValue": "B08GLYFTFQ"
    }
]
```

if i now set the variable "IsAmazonFulfilled" to false, the whole thing works smoothly. however, my problem is that i now don't get the FBA fees i need.
before i already query the buybox price via "getCompetitivePricing".

does anyone have a more precise idea how i can determine if a product can be fulfilled by amazon at all?

best regards